# Как из одного класса вызвать метод другого класса?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Здравствуйте.

Вопрос по Action Script 3.

Хочу выяснить одну проблему. **Как из одного класса вызвать метод другого класса?**
В примере, который здесь показан, у меня почему-то картинка не  вырисовывается. В классе FirstClass вызывается метод qwadrat класса SecondClass. В этом методе должен быть зеленый квадрат на сцене. Но его у меня нет. Что не так?

Или лучше напишите шаблон для вызова метода другого класса.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import SecondClass;

    public class FirstClass extends Sprite
    {
        public function FirstClass()
        {
            var kartinka:SecondClass = new SecondClass();
            kartinka.qwadrat();
        }
    }
}

package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class SecondClass extends Sprite
    {
        public var qw:Sprite = new Sprite();

        public function qwadrat():void
        {
            qw.graphics.lineStyle(1);
            qw.graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00);
            qw.graphics.drawRect(20, 20, 200, 200);
            qw.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(qw);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `kartinka` => `image`

`qwadrat` => `rectangle`

Answer (score 1):

Так вы SecondClass никуда не добавили, как я понимаю... Ему тоже надо addChild вызвать.

Comment: SecondClass является классом и к нему не применяется метод addChild.
Я так считаю.
В классе FirstClass был создан экземпляр класса SecondClass -  kartinka, с вызовом конструктора и тем самым он уже создан.
Метод addChild применяется к экранным объектам.

Comment: метод addChild() применим ко всем классам унаследованным от класса Sprite, 

    class SecondClass extends Sprite

не исключение.

Comment: Вопрос?
Как применить метод addChild к классу?
В данном случае к классу SecondClass в классе FirstClass.

Comment: отображается всё, что так или иначе добавлено в главный контрол

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    

если у вас он вынесен в глобальную переменную, например, можете хоть сразу писать вместо

    addChild(qw);
    
что-то вроде

    mainControl.addChild(qw);

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить в классе FirstClass **addChild(kartinka.qw);**
таким образом:

public class FirstClass extends Sprite
{

```
public function FirstClass()
{    
    var kartinka:SecondClass = new SecondClass();
    kartinka.qwadrat();         
    addChild(kartinka.qw);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

stage.addChild(qw); нужно было в SecondClass  написать!

Comment: Таким образом при добавлении в SecondClass не работает.
Нужно писать в FirstClass.
А addChild(qw) или stage.addChild(qw) не особенно важно.
Теперь работает.